# Onkeypress event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am working one application ,in this application I need to show the `typing indicator` , I am able to show that `indicator` ,when the user is `typing` I am sending a message to receiver that the user is typing, I am sending this message continuously when the user `press`  with `onkeypress event` any `key`, Now my question is I want to send this `message` when the user starts `typing` and next `message` I want to send after `20 Seconds`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+onkeypress+detect+user+typing+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you asked for but here it is:

```
      setTimeout(() => yourFunction(args), 20000);
```

the function will be called after 20 seconds, you can define the function to check for key presses and then send the `is typing`.

Comment: Sohan jahanmard: I want first time to call immediately and second time to call after 20 seconds

Comment: So `yourFunction(args); setTimeout(() => yourFunction(args), 20000);`

Comment: You want to send message 20 seconds after user starts typing, or after user stops typing? If so, you need to cancel the last scheduled action. Declare "let timeoutId=null;" somewhere and on every keyPress event execute "if (timeoutId) { clearTimeout(timeoutId); } timeoutId = setTimeout(() => yourFunction(args), 20000)